# How do you turn an upper bound of the second Chebyshev function into a corresponding lower bound?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, chebyshev-function

In Table 5.1 on page 103 of the book *The Riemann Hypothesis for Function Fields: Frobenius Flow and Shift Operators* by Machiel van Frankenhuijsen the author states:

> $$\textit{Riemann hypothesis} \iff \psi(x)=x+O(x^{1/2+\epsilon}) \iff \psi(x) \le x+O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$$

where $\psi(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{p^k \le x} \log(p)$ is the second [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function).

He also writes (a page earlier):

> As a consequence of the density in the real line of the values $\log \left\lvert x \right\rvert$ $(x \in \mathbb{Q})$, it becomes unnecessary to establish the lower bound ...

He leaves it at that, however, and neither have I found this worked out somewhere nor have I been able to fill in the details. So

**Question:** How do you proof that an upper bound is enough? That is, how do you use the density of  $\log \left\lvert x \right\rvert$ $(x \in \mathbb{Q})$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to turn the upper bound into a lower bound?

Comment: Haven't  seen this argument  before, but the result  you want (upper bound enough) follows from Landau theorem on dirichlet integrals that have constant sign integrand as that implies either RH true or zeta has a real zero between $(.5,1)$ and the latter is false

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis implies $|\psi(x)-x|<\frac{1}{8\pi} \sqrt{x} \log^2 x$ for all $x\ge 73.2$.
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers). Wikipedia gives a reference for this claim that might answer your question.